# How to fill out a column with mock data where value is null

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Can somebody show me the way how to do this?

Let's say I've got the following result:

```
APP ¦    DAY   ¦ PERCENT
------------------------
JKL ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦ 
JKL ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ 
JKL ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ 78
JKL ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ 
JKL ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ 64
JKL ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ 
JKL ¦ 2017-02-11 ¦ 
TZU ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦ 97
TZU ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ 
TZU ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ 
TZU ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ 24
TZU ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ 23
TZU ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ 
TZU ¦ 2017-02-11 ¦ 
UIO ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦
..
.
```

I would like to transform the above result into this:

```
APP ¦   DAY  ¦ PERCENT
----------------------
JKL ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦ 100
JKL ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ 100
JKL ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ 78
JKL ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ 78
JKL ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ 64
JKL ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ 64
JKL ¦ 2017-02-11 ¦ 64
TZU ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦ 97
TZU ¦ 2017-02-06 ¦ 97
TZU ¦ 2017-02-07 ¦ 97
TZU ¦ 2017-02-08 ¦ 24
TZU ¦ 2017-02-09 ¦ 23
TZU ¦ 2017-02-10 ¦ 23
TZU ¦ 2017-02-11 ¦ 23
UIO ¦ 2017-02-05 ¦ 100
..
.
```

So I need some kind of code which starts to check "APP" and until the last "DAY" repeats the previous record value @"PERCENT" if its empty, starting by 100 except the first entry (per APP) was been already filled out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `last_value()` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions097.htm#SQLRF00655) to achieve this. If the current value is null, look for the last value for `app` (which is the `partition by` clause) in date order (`order by day`), ignoring any nulls - so you look back for the previous non-null value for the `app`:

```
select app, to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day,
  nvl(percent, last_value (percent ignore nulls)
    over (partition by app order by day)) as percent
from my_table
order by app, day;

APP DAY           PERCENT
--- ---------- ----------
JKL 2017-02-05           
JKL 2017-02-06           
JKL 2017-02-07         78
JKL 2017-02-08         78
JKL 2017-02-09         64
JKL 2017-02-10         64
JKL 2017-02-11         64
TZU 2017-02-05         97
TZU 2017-02-06         97
TZU 2017-02-07         97
TZU 2017-02-08         24
TZU 2017-02-09         23
TZU 2017-02-10         23
TZU 2017-02-11         23
UIO 2017-02-05
```

I've use `nvl()` but you can use `case` if you prefer. To fill in the missing 100 values you can use `nvl()` or `case` again:

```
select app, to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day,
  nvl(percent, nvl(last_value (percent ignore nulls)
    over (partition by app order by day), 100)) as percent
from my_table
order by app, day;

APP DAY           PERCENT
--- ---------- ----------
JKL 2017-02-05        100
JKL 2017-02-06        100
JKL 2017-02-07         78
JKL 2017-02-08         78
JKL 2017-02-09         64
JKL 2017-02-10         64
JKL 2017-02-11         64
TZU 2017-02-05         97
TZU 2017-02-06         97
TZU 2017-02-07         97
TZU 2017-02-08         24
TZU 2017-02-09         23
TZU 2017-02-10         23
TZU 2017-02-11         23
UIO 2017-02-05        100
```

Other analytic functions could be used instead - `lag()`, or by reversing the order, `lead()` or `first_value()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can initially set the first row to 100 if it has a null value for a given app. Then use `LAG` with `IGNORE NULLS` option to get the previous non-null value.

```
SELECT APP,
       DT,
       CASE WHEN NEW_PERCENT IS NOT NULL THEN NEW_PERCENT
       ELSE LAG(NEW_PERCENT IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY APP ORDER BY DT)
       END AS PERCENT
FROM
 (SELECT T.*,
         CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY APP ORDER BY DT) = 1 AND PERCENT IS NULL THEN 100
         ELSE PERCENT
         END AS NEW_PERCENT
  FROM T
  ) X
```